# can register user control one page

Tags: nodes, users

How can I make registered user take control (Edit/View/Delete) a piece of content type; a specific page for example. is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide if this will be role based or user based. If it is Role based you can use the default permission system in Drupal.

If you want it per user consider using [Content Access Module](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) in conjunciton with [ACL module](https://drupal.org/project/acl)

Answer (score 0):

Permission is given by administrator to registered user

1. Go to People -> Permission in admin panel
2. select edit  any content for  new  Edit/View/Delete role

   [image]

   and also you need to used **user permission module**

   User Permissions provides an interface for giving additional permissions to individual users without the need to assign them to a special role. When this module is enabled, users with the 'administer permissions' permission can access the 'User Permissions' tab on each user's account.